# Making a double division

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a double divion with this code:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
double result = (a + b) / 4;
```

How to get a `2.5` as a result and not `2`, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Divide by 4.0 or explicitly cast a number to double before using it

Answer (score 0):

One of the arguments needs to be a `double`. So:

```
double result = (a + b) / 4.0;
```

Or

```
double result = (double)(a + b) / 4;
```

Comment: that wouldn't work :/

Comment: Are you sure? I've checked both examples...

Comment: I don't know but on my example this wouldn't.

Comment: @opd what if `double result = (a + b) / c`? where `double c = 4.0;`